# How to connect to my local machine domain from docker container?

Tags: windows, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have local server with domain *mydomain.com* it is just alias to localhost:80
And I want to allow make requests to mydomain.com from my running docker-container.
When I'm trying to request to it I see

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to mydomain.com port 80: Connection refused
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: project-nginx
    image: nginx:1.23.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - ${NGINX_PORT:-81}:80
    depends_on:
      - project
  server:
    container_name: project
    build:
      context: ./
    environment:
      NODE_MODE: service
      APP_ENV: local
      APP_DEBUG: 1
      ALLOWED_ORIGINS: ${ALLOWED_ORIGINS:-null}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
```

I'm using docker desktop for Windows
What can I do?

I've tried to add

```
network_mode: "host"
```

but it ruins my docker-compose startup
When I'm trying to send request to host.docker.internal I see this:

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered
> the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The host network is not supported on Windows. If you are using Linux containers on Windows, make sure you have switched to Linux containers on Docker Desktop. That uses WSL2, so you should be able to use that in there.